# OSx How to create a fat binary from two different binaries which depend on each other

Tags: macos, makefile, openssl, binary, stunnel

Basically what I want to do is to create a binary which contains Stunnel and openssl(stunnel depends on openssl) and to work on any mac without installing anything, just by running that binary I want Stunnel to work.
I downloaded the source code for both programs, I run  `./configure` whit the required parameters, and run `make` also with the required parameters.

Both of them creates two binaries which can be executed, how can I concatenate both of them, and all the files they need into creating a fat universal binary which can be executed on any OSx system.
I need some guidance, some tutorials to read. I searched a lot, found different stuff which I don't know if they are correct. Mostly I find about `lipo` but this doesn't help me on combining two different binaries, of the same architecture, in one big fat binary.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong technology.  Fat binaries do not serve to combine multiple distinct programs into the same executable.  Rather, they put the binary code for two or more architectures for *the same* program into one file.  To combine multiple related programs and maybe associated data / config / libraries, you want to build a [bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)).

Comment: If you truly require a single binary that provides all the needed behavior and data then you will need to modify the C code of the programs involved, and write at least a bit of your own, to merge the programs into one, and to build in any data that are normally external.  If you also want to avoid external library dependencies then you will have to link against static libraries when you build.  Doing all that successfully will result in a dependency-free single *thin* binary.  You could go on to make fat binaries of it, but that's a separate consideration.